# SQL query distinct issue

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have written the below query to list all the rows in table [HRSurvey]
which empid is only present in empsurveyselection. Both table have empid columns.

But i am not able to get the proper results because there 
might be multiple empid for same surveyid in empsurveyselection table.
But this query works fine when there is only one empid for each surveyid in empsurveyselection table.

Could you please rewrite the query to list the all the rows in the table HRSurvey where the empid are there in empsurveyselection   ?

```
SELECT  hrs.* 
  FROM [HRSurvey] hrs
Left Join [HRSurveyEmployee] hse
ON hse.EmpID =  hrs.EmpID 
LEFT Join Surveys s 
ON s.surveyid = hse.surveyid 
WHERE hrs.empid IN (
SELECT empid FROM [HRSurveyEmployee] where surveyid = s.surveyid 
) and sempid 
in ( select DISTINCT empid FROM empsurveyselection WHERE deptid=9 and surveyid = s.surveyid)
```

Comment: If you get the wrong result, it's not because there are duplicate values in the `empsurveyselection` table. The `in` operator doesn't give you multiple results when there are duplicates, e.g. `in (1,2,2,2,2,3)` would not cause the record with the value `2` to be repeated four times, it has the same meaning as `in (1,2,3)`. The `distinct` specifier in the query is superflous inside the `in`.

Comment: what is the solution?

Comment: To know that we need to know what the problem is. As it's not the `in` operation that causes duplicates, you have to examine the data to find out what's actually causing it.

Comment: Is there are reason for using a left join? As you are using a value from the table in the `where` clause, it's making the join work as an inner join, so that would be a problem if you need the left join.

Answer (score 3):

You can write as:

```
SELECT hrs.col1, -- Worst Practice to use * in production code to pull data
       hrs.col12 -- Use explicit column names instead
FROM [HRSurvey] hrs
INNER JOIN [HRSurveyEmployee] hse ON hse.EmpID =  hrs.EmpID 
INNER JOIN [Surveys] s ON s.surveyid = hse.surveyid 
INNER JOIN [empsurveyselection]ess ON ess.deptid=9 
AND ess.surveyid = s.surveyid AND hrs.sempid = ess.empid
```

Comment: i tried this as well the problem is there is a third primary key for empsurveyselection called questionid, which will reapeat the rows again .. how to prevent this?

Comment: suppose the row count of the hrsurvey is 2000 , when i add the last inner join , empsurveyselection , it will add more rows in the result because there is another primary key question id (thrid pk) other than surveyid and empid which will duplicates the records

Comment: Are you pulling data from `empsurveyselection` as well? as you have written `hrs.* `?

Comment: no i am not ...but i need to see the existance of records in empsurveyselection to list the records in hrsurvey

Answer (score 1):

Please try with the below query....

```
select  a.*
from    HRSurvey a
where   empid exists (select  1
                      from    empsurveyselection b
                      where   a.Empid = b.Empid)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help! Actually issue was not with the query. Issue was with the data and i fixed it.